# Overload function not working during sending request from angular to express

Tags: html, node.js, angular, express, overloading

when the deposit function call it return value the response after operations in backend

```
getToken(){
    // fetch the token from local storage
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token') || '');
    // generate header
    let header = new HttpHeaders()
    //append token inside header
    if(token){
      options.headers = header.append('x-access-token', token);
    }
    return options
  }

  deposit(acno:any, pswd:any, dAmt:any){
    const body = {
      acno:acno,
      password:pswd,
      dAmt:dAmt
    }
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/deposit', body, this.getToken());
  }
```

getToken function is for sent token through headers,const body in deposit function are the value request through body.when i sent only body value,it will work and alert about token.
so i need to sent header value too.for that i created getToken and to work overload i created a global object like this:

```
// Global http header object 
const options = {
  headers:new HttpHeaders()
}
```

I didnt get any response after sending header value request.
In console show like this:

> ERROR SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
> getToken data.service.ts:57
> deposit data.service.ts:73
> deposit dashboard.component.ts:41
> DashboardComponent_Template_button_click_26_listener dashboard.component.html:24

Comment: your error is about parsing the value of the token that is already stored in the localStorage. In my opnion, you should look at the code where you store the token data in the lcoalStorage, may be it is not a valid Json object

Comment: yes its the problem of localstorage.The "t" of  token is "T" its worked now.